# SceneKit Draw Infinite Grid View in XZ Plane similar to XCode Scene Editor

Tags: ios, scenekit, metal

I tried using the SCNFloor and Material, but it draws with limited width and length.

Is there any way I can generate an infinite grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this could be the issue: Have you checked the zFar value of your SCNCamera? the Default is: 100m (this means everything that's more fare away is clipped by the renderer) - you might want to set it to a really high value and also disable the automaticallyAdjustZRange property (what should be the default). Hope I could help you.

Comment: automazicallyAdjustZRange does it required for zoom in and out? I also need to pan, zoom in and zoom out of the scene.  Do you have any Idea for Xcode Scene Editor is drawing the grid with the show and hide function? Exactly what I needed.

Comment: You could make a SCNPlane with Material T and S Wrapped and/or scaled, infinite texture on it (can also contain transparent alpha channel), that gives you a grid as big as you want. automazicallyAdjustZRange is not used for zooming. you can adjust the focus on the camera, like with a Pan Handler or a Slider element.

Comment: how do I set the color for the central axis line any idea? only the main axis x= 0 and z=0 need to be in two different colors.